# Reset all the filter schemes (including used and un-used) in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Is there any way to reset all the filter schemes? I understood that using the "Action Control", we are able to reset only the filter scheme used in the report but not all. I am trying to reset all the filter scheme. Appreciate your kind support.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a python script attached to a button to loop through all of your filtering schemes and reset them:

```
#reset all filters
for i in range(0,Document.FilteringSchemes.Count):
    Document.FilteringSchemes[i].ResetAllFilters()
```

If the filtering scheme exists, it will reset all the filters it holds.

Comment: Thank you clesiemo3. It works fine. I also tried with the following.  `for scheme in Document.FilteringSchemes:
scheme.ResetAllFilters()`

Answer (score 0):

The "Reset All Filters" in the available Actions resets only the active filtering scheme. If you have multiple filtering schemes on the same page or in the report you need the script provided by clesiemo3.

If you want to reset all visible filters, use the script found [here](http://spotfired.blogspot.nl/2014/08/reset-visible-filters.html)